# file copy program in binary mode

Tags: c#

I am writing a filecopy program, but reading data from a media file such as .avi in binary mode into the string variable str throws an error related to the size of the variable str not being large enough to hold the data returned from the file read.
Here is the code through which i was trying to perform the task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename;
            Console.WriteLine("enter file location");
            filename=Console.ReadLine();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            string str;
            str =Convert.ToString(br.Read());
            while (str != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                str = Convert.ToString(br.Read());
            }
            fs.Close();
            br.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

what's the solution to this.

Comment: Why are you reading data into a `string` instead of, say, a `byte[]`?

Comment: You can just use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx) instead

Answer (score 4):

Simply, don't ever involve `string` if you are talking about binary. As a consequence, though, it doesn't make much sense to write to the console unless the console is in binary mode. A basic binary copy loop would be something like:

```
using(var inputStream = OpenSomeStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    while((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
       // TODO: write "read"-many bytes from buffer
    }
}
```

however, for a stream-to-stream copy, this can be abbreviated to:

```
using(var inputStream = OpenSomeStream())
using(var outputStream = OpenSomeOtherStream()) {
    inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```

so: for writing to `stdout`, this would be:

```
using(var inputStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
using(var outputStream = Console.OpenStandardOutput()) {
    inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```